# R array, count rows since first incidence of a specific value

Tags: r, arrays, apply

I need to figure out a method of reading a 2d array, by column and finding the first instance of a specific entry, in this case 3, and then counting down the rows so that each row increments successive rows.  I've tried with apply statements but it is working in both margins, and also having some trouble with functions returning inf.  Here is my mwe. Thx.J

```
arr1 <- as.array (matrix (c (NA, NA, 8, NA, 2, 3, 3,
                             NA, 3, 8, NA, 2, 3, 3,
                             3, NA, 8, NA, 9, 5, 2),
           ncol = 3)
          )

> arr1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA    3
[2,]   NA    3   NA
[3,]    8    8    8
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    2    2    9
[6,]    3    3    5
[7,]    3    3    2
```

So I need to find the first instance of 3 in each column, i.e r6c1, r2c2, r1,c3 and I can find these using this

```
apply(arr1, 2, function (x) min(which(x == 3 )))
```

but then I get lost.  The final product I would like to get looks like this, in array format

```
> arr2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    2
[4,]    0    2    3
[5,]    0    3    4
[6,]    0    4    5
[7,]    1    5    6
```

Now trying this, and getting an error.  Not sure why, thought it should work on any matrix/2d array? Thx.J

```
> arr1 <- as.array (matrix (c (NA, NA, 8, NA, 2, 3, 3,
                               NA, 3, 8, NA, 2, 3, 3,
                               3, NA, 8, NA, 9, 5, 4,
                               8, 7, NA, 9, 5, 4, 2,
                               8, 5, 2, 9, 7, 5, 3), ncol = 5))
> 
> arr1 = cbind(arr1,1)
> 
> apply(arr1,2,function(x){
+   if(any(x==3)){
+     n = min(which(x==3))
+     c(rep(0,n-1),1:(length(x)-n+1) -1)
+   }else{rep(0,length(x))}
+ })  
Error in if (any(x == 3)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps.

```
n <- nrow(arr1)
a <- apply(arr1, 2, function (x) min(which(x == 3 )))
Reduce(cbind, lapply(a, function(x){
  q <- seq(n) - x
  q * (q>0)
}))
```

Outputs

```
     init    
[1,]    0 0 0
[2,]    0 0 1
[3,]    0 1 2
[4,]    0 2 3
[5,]    0 3 4
[6,]    0 4 5
[7,]    1 5 6
```

Naming might be weird due to my environment.

If you have missing values or columns without 3s then this will fix.

```
n <- nrow(arr1)
a <- apply(arr1, 2, function (x) {
    x <- suppressWarnings(min(which(x == 3)))
    ifelse(is.finite(x), x, n+1)
  })
res <- Reduce(cbind, lapply(a, function(x){
    q <- seq(n) - x
    q * (q>0)
}))
```

Output on arr1

```
> arr1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA   NA    3    8    8    1
[2,]   NA    3   NA    7    5    1
[3,]    8    8    8   NA    2    1
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    9    9    1
[5,]    2    2    9    5    7    1
[6,]    3    3    5    4    5    1
[7,]    3    3    4    2    3    1
> res
     init          
[1,]    0 0 0 0 0 0
[2,]    0 0 1 0 0 0
[3,]    0 1 2 0 0 0
[4,]    0 2 3 0 0 0
[5,]    0 3 4 0 0 0
[6,]    0 4 5 0 0 0
[7,]    1 5 6 0 0 0
```

Comment: Same problem here ... getting missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error ....

Comment: I've edited it so its a little better with NAs and columns without 3s.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, just have to churn out the 0s and increments, I also added a if, else because in situations where there's no "3", the which will throw an error:

```
# test when there is no 3s
arr1 = cbind(arr1,1)

apply(arr1,2,function(x){
  if(any(x==3)){
    n = min(which(x==3))
    c(rep(0,n-1),1:(length(x)-n+1) -1)
  }else{rep(0,length(x))}
})  

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    2    0
[4,]    0    2    3    0
[5,]    0    3    4    0
[6,]    0    4    5    0
[7,]    1    5    6    0
```

Comment: Thx@StupidWolf, for some reason I get an error "Error in if (any(x == 3)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>

Comment: you ran the code on arr1 you provided or something else?

Comment: Thx again StupidWolf.  I've edited the original question, this is what I get and not sure why? Is it anything to do with arrays/vectors vs data.frames for these functions?